# cumulative sum per day in rails&postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ive got a table 'donations' which is filled (by users) on a daily basis. I would like to create a graph that shows the cumulative number of donations per day.

So,

```
table donations:
id  created_at
1   19/01 
2   20/01
3   20/01
4   21/01
```

Should become:

```
[1,3,4]
```

How to do this with rails3&postgresql? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its actually quite easy..

simply select "DISTINCT"... ok, this was a n00b question, figured it out! for the people that want to know more > [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns-postgresql)